# Separate react component to another repo / create private npm package

Tags: git, reactjs, npm, repository, bitbucket

I have a big react project with many components and what I need is to separate one component to another repository

I've read about it and I want to do it something like npm package, but it has to be private. 
Private npm package cost 7 usd / month and client doesn't want this solution

Is there any other option, for example import component from bitbucket repository?
Or somehow create free private lib which will be able to add to project and build?

I've found some tools like **sinopia** but it's abandonware (last update 2014)

What will be the best solution?